# Outlook mail authentication

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I have created an REST API and it will be consumed from an outlook web mail addins which I also build. Now, I want to make sure that only those who logged-in in Outlook web mail can get access to my API.

So my question now, is how to get the active user in outlook web mail? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate your user for service you have implemented. There are several ways of doing this, please read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication.

Please read about Addin API 'getUserIdentityTokenAsync' which looks like what you are looking for in this case.